# sql query for finding multiple duplicate pairs in columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as below:

```
paper_id  author_id     author_name         author_affiliation
    1     521630         Ayman Kaheel        Cairo Microsoft Innovation Lab
    1     972575       Mahmoud Refaat       Cairo Microsoft Innovation Lab
    3    1528710     Ahmed Abdul-hamid      Harvard
```

Now I am finding multiple pairs of `author_id`, `author_name` and `author_affiliation` occuring together. For example:

```
author_id     author_name     author_affiliation  count
   1          Masuo Fukui               <NA>       4
   4          Yasusada Yamada           <NA>       8
```

I am using the following query:

```
statement<-"select author_id,author_name,author_affiliation,count(*)
        from paper_author 
        GROUP BY author_id,author_name,author_affiliation
        HAVING (COUNT(*)>1)"
```

Now I want to know how many author_ids are present in this. I am doing this:

```
statement<-"select distinct author_id 
    from paper_author 
     where author_id in (
        select author_id,author_name,author_affiliation,count(*)
        from paper_author 
        GROUP BY author_id,author_name,author_affiliation
        HAVING (COUNT(*)>1)
    )"
```

I am not able to get the desired result.

Also, how can I get the number of paper ids in the above result?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for the total number of rows, the total number of unique/distinct author_id values or the total number of duplicate entries?

Comment: Your IN clause is wrong. You select too many values. Try: where author_id in (select author_id from paper_author ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job, i think:

```
statement<-"select distinct author_id 
    from paper_author 
     where author_id in (
        select author_id
        from paper_author 
        GROUP BY author_id,author_name,author_affiliation
        HAVING (COUNT(*)>1)
    )"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how many authors have more than one paper, use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT author_id, author_affiliation, COUNT(*)
      FROM paper_author 
      GROUP BY author_id, author_affiliation
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

This assumes that `author_id` is a unique identifier for `author_name`. If the id selects for the `author_name, author_affiliation` combination (i.e. an author producing papers for different institutions has multiple id's, one for each affiliation) then you can also strike `author_affiliation` from the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query slightly re-written. You don't need an IN clause. You can select directly from your result set.

```
select distinct author_id 
from 
(
  select author_id
  from paper_author 
  group by author_id,author_name,author_affiliation
  having count(*) > 1
);
```